# External display often does not wake up

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

I have a "mid-2012" MacBook Air 13" running Mojave 10.14.4

Since around Sierra or High Sierra time I have had a problem where frequently my external display does not come on when I plug it in or wake my laptop. It is inconsistent, but a significant proportion of the time, the screen does not wake.

Screen is a Dell U2417 connected via the TB/miniDP port on the laptop to either DisplayPort input (screen at work) or HDMI input (same screen at home).

Symptoms:

- the MacBook recognises that the screen is attached

  - screen shows in display preferences
  - the desktop reconfigures as if screen connected (i.e. the laptop screen changes resolution to match the external screen, even though external screen does not wake up)
- if I switch the screen off and on it just says "no signal" and goes to sleep
- unplugging and re-plugging the screen does not fix the problem, symptoms just repeated (desktop reconfigures, screen does not respond)
- rebooting the laptop fixes the problem

Since it works sometimes and works after reboot it seems to me the problem must be a software or firmware one, rather than a hardware issue.

It is a major pain in the neck having to reboot often because of this issue.

NOTE here https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/U2718Q-MacBook-Pro-won-t-wake-up/td-p/6072760
Dell tech support has basically told Mac users to get stuffed
Perhaps the problem is specific to Dell monitors, I see a few questions about similar issues with Dell + macOS.

Comment: Some of my users are having the same problem, were you able to find a solution elsewhere?

Comment: @DanatheSane not yet. I am trying an experiment: when I get home I open the laptop and log-in _before_ connecting the external display (then close it after the external screen comes on... I leave my laptop in "clamshell" mode at home).  It seems to work so far but need more data...

Comment: Same problems but with a slightly different set of components: Mac mini 2018 intel and a LG monitor. Have had less problems while using thunderbolt cable vs a HDMI cable. Thunderbolt works like 60%-70% of the time, while HDMI is like 20-30%. Note: have been using the same monitor with a handful of other MacBooks like pros and airs and they never had any problem with this monitor. The problem is definitely in the Mac mini.

Comment: I normally disable any sleep state etc in macOS settings just to avoid the risk of the screen not waking up in case the screen goes to sleep.